# Why do you need to wrap GraphQL mutations?

Tags: graphql, mutation

I have never understood why GraphQL mutations need to be "wrapped".  You'll often see something like this demonstrated (assuming a mutation named `addThing` which requires a `name`):

```
mutation addThing($name: String!) {
  addThing(name: $name) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

However, the outer "wrapper" could be named *anything*. For example, the following nonsense works equally well:

```
mutation nonsense($name: String!) {
  addThing(name: $name) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

What is the reasoning for "wrapping" the mutations this way?

Comment: it's an 'operation name'.... not widely used ... but you can have different operations (with different args) using the same mutation

Comment: I see... I can imagine operations that wrap several mutations.  How would you write the mutation _without_ the operation name?

Comment: by specs it's optional https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Language.Operations  ... when only one operation in query